# Where should tests for flutter be kept

Tags: flutter, directory-structure

Do they have to be in the root tests foder? When using react I prefer to keep my tests near the components, can I do this with flutter? If not, is it recommended to store all tests in the one test folder or duplicate the structure of lib?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It depends on the different type of test (`unit`, `widget`, or `integration`) but the need to be located in specific folders.

From [Flutters CookBook Guides](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/testing/unit/introduction):

> In general, test files should reside inside a test folder located at the root of your Flutter application or package.

Unit and Widget tests must be located in a `test` folder.
Integration test must go in a separate directory called `test_driver`. Both folders must be located same level as your `lib` folder.